# I can't align an image to the right

Tags: html, css, alignment, right-align

I tried everything but could not align the image to the right.

I tried to search all around the internet, and worked on this problem for several days. I used `text-align: right;` and `margin: right;` and many more. I expected that it would align to the right, but instead it didn't and resulted in it getting bigger and smaller. Can you help me?

Comment: How we can help you without your code? Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is to use flexbox.

```
<body>
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: end;">
    <img src="..." alt="...">
</div>
</body>
```

And you have to make sure the parent div-element has a width of 100%. You can check that by using the inspector of your browser.

(Firefox: cmd/strg + shift + c,
Safari/Chrome: cmd/strg + shift + i,
or just use right-click and choose 'inspect' on the bottom)